# about Bitcoin address

Tags: wallet, address

I'm studying bitcoin.
I have a question because I was curious about the part of wallet.

1. Can I send it to the wrong address format?
2. The address format is correct, but is it possible to send bitcoin if sent to the ownerless address?
3. If 'A' happens to generate `question2 address` and use its wallet address, can 'A' use its coin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I send it to the wrong address format?

Addresses have checksums in them to prevent mistakes like these. Typographical errors can be detected because of these checksums. So a well designed wallet will not allow this, but nothing prevents a badly designed program from erroneously accepting an incorrect address format and decoding it into some invalid/impossible output script.

> The address format is correct, but is it possible to send bitcoin if sent to the ownerless address?

Addresses don't have owners. They have keys or other requirements associated with them. If coins are sent to an address for which the key is not known, or to an address with unknown redeem script requirements or impossible redeemscript requirements, then the coins are permanently lost.

> If 'A' happens to generate question2 address and use its wallet address, can 'A' use its coin?

If you miraculously manage to generate the private key of an address that has bitcoins sent to it then, yes, you can spend those coins. However, the likelihood of that happening is infinitesimal.

Comment: Thank you! Everything I was curious about was solved.  
Lastly, is there any other way to check bitcoin address besides checking the checksum, checking the version?